# How to place button in search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a search box with button inside as Google map. For the search box, it is very easy to create by following [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). However, I couldn't find out how to add a menu button as what they did in Google map. See the following picture for more details.
Thanks.

[image]

EDIT: To be clear, I'm referring to the menu button on the left which lies inside the search box. It is not the blue arrow button on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Add the last line into your example to add a button that will appear next to your search box. You will need to write a function that will tell the button what to do when it is clicked.

```
<body>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box"
<button onclick="doStuff()">Press to Search</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Could you please provide a fiddle implementation?

Comment: The button is added. You need to make a function that will tell the button what to do. In the example above it would be a function called "doStuff()"

Comment: Actually, I'm referring to the menu button, which will show the hidden sidebar when being clicked. It is not the "arrow" button